# Recently released iPhone app update hangs at splash screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I submitted my app update for review a week or so ago and it worked fine for me when i submitted it (on multiple devices and emulator).  Apple reviewed it and approved it and now whenever users download it, the app just hangs at the splash screen forever.  On iOS 6 beta it immediately crashes.  I believe it must be something wrong with the package that Apple put on the store for download, but i honestly have no idea.  Anybody had this happen before or anyone have any ideas on how you can debug a problem like this?

This is maybe the 30th or so time i've submitted something to Apple and this is the first time anything like this has ever happened.  I have used a technical support incident to contact apple and no response so far from that.  I also used the contact us page on the itunesconnect portal to ask about it and no response from that either.  Both of those were done on Friday.  As a secondary question, does anyone know how long it takes to hear back from Apple when you submit questions in either of those ways?

Comment: Did you tested on different supported iOS's ? Specifically tested on latest released iOS 5.1.1 ?

Comment: Was this app built with any iOS 6 frameworks?

Comment: _As a secondary question, does anyone know how long it takes to hear back from Apple when you submit questions in either of those ways?_ Totally random, for me it is in range 1 week - 2 months

Comment: The app was built and tested on iOS 4 and 5.  I was just throwing that out there that when it is on iOS 6 it doesn't hang, it crashes immediately.

Comment: So, did you download your own app and see if it will run on your device? Did you ask a friend who is close by who has not had it try it? In either case with a crash, you can retrieve the crash report. You can also ask some user who reported a crash to send you the crash report. If its a free app then tell us the name, we'll download and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, i downloaded it and ran it on my device.  The same thing happens to me.  As far as i can tell there is no crash report associated with this problem.  The app never really crashes, it just stays at the splash screen forever.

I got a hold of someone in technical support and they assured me that someone did look at it before it was released to the store, so i'm still thinking it must be something that's happened to the binary when they loaded it into the store for download.  Oh well, I submitted another update hoping that this one will go through correctly.  Oh well...

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.  On my end, the app runs/installs fine on the device (connection and through adhoc).  However, when it gets to the store most of the time it hangs on the Splash screen (Default.png) file.  We have found that on some non-iPhone-5 devices it works was it should.  No way to reproduce it and no crash log.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. It was a **DNS** issue. It drove me mad for months, since I could not reproduce the issue. However one poorly configured WiFi helped me reproduce the issue by chance.

iOS tries to perform DNS lookup at the beginning of the app lifecyle. This is even before a single line of code is executed. If the DNS lookup is performed on the main thread synchronously, it blocks the UI. This issue arises only in cases where its trying to resolve the DNS for about 30s while blocking the UI. Hence the iOS watchdog kills the app due to a timeout. Apple also has a doc for this- https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html

You can search for DNS lookup in your code and check its execution. In my case it was a 3rd party C-library that was causing an issue.

I know its been really long since this question was asked, hope it helps someone.